# Python CSV - find and output a specific row

Tags: python, csv

I am currently trying to write a simple code to do the following: ask the user for an e-mail adress of a client. The code shuould then check if this client is already registered and his data (including email) can be found in the overall client csv and propose the data from this specific raw to the user so that the data does not have to be typed again.

I have tried the following code but all it does is to iterare over all raws in my csv, since I have used the "print" command to check also in cases where the mail is not found in the raw, I can see, that the program iterates over the lines in which the email is included but treats the line as if the mail was not in there.

Is there maybe an even more elegant way to check if the mail is in the raw since the raw output in the code seems to give a dictionary, but when I try to compare the input mail to e.g. (data["Mail"]) I get a key error.

So here's the code, I am really looking forward for answers since I cant work out where the mistake might be.

```
def check_mail():
    mail=m1.get()
    print ("Mail input: ", mail)
    with open ("daten\daten_diesel_neu.csv", newline="\n") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            data = row
            print(data)
            if mail in data:
                print ("the mail you entered belongs to the following data: ", row)
                client_data = data
            else:
                print ("mail not in ", row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your csv file has a header, e.g. `First Name, Last Name, Email, ...` then your row will look something like that: `[('First Name', 'Frank'), ('Email', 'info@spam.com'), ('Last Name', 'The Tank')]`. What you are doing is to check if `mail` is in the row, but row is always a Dictionary and by checking if something is in a `dict` you will only iterate through the Keys. So for each Key you need also to iterate through the value of each Key. Also I recommend to use a `break` command to stop your search when you found it.

```
def check_mail():
    mail=m1.get()
    print ("Mail input: ", mail)
    with open ("daten\daten_diesel_neu.csv", newline="\n") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            data = row
            print(data)
            for item in data:
                if mail in data[item]:
                    print ("the mail you entered belongs to the following data: ", row)
                    client_data = data
                    break
                else:
                    print ("mail not in ", row)
```